# Error with basic Windows 7 Folder Redirection on Server 2003 domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, folder-redirection

I am trying to set up folder redirection for users on Windows 7 machines on a Windows Server 2003 domain.  I have applied the "Basic" Folder Redirection group policy for the "Documents" folder to redirect to "Create a folder for each user under the root path:"

\dc\profiles\

When I try to log on as the user, the folder is not redirecting and shows the user's local c:\users\user\Documents folder under Libraries.  I check Event Viewer and I see the following error:

```
 The following error occurred: "Can not create folder "\\dc\profiles\dmunch\Documents"".
 Error details: "Access is denied.
".
```

However, when I Start > Run logged in as the user's profile, I can copy and paste the UNC path to the share in the run location and browse to it with no problems.

\dc\profiles\dmunch\Documents

Why am I unable to use this folder as-is?  I assumed it had something to do with Security, however I am able to browse to the folder with no problems.

*Note- I am NOT using roaming profiles, only folder redirection.  No other group policies are active except: Computer: disallow CTRL+ALT+DELETE at login, and login message.

**Note 2- I created the Group Policy on a Windows 7 machine so I would get all of the Windows 7 features on a 2003 domain/policy.

***Note 3- The user is the owner of both their root profile folder and the documents folder with full control permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used these articles to set permissions on the root of the redirected share:

I found that setting permissions on the share was necessary at this link:

http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/performance/configure-folder-redirection.html

This helped to tell me which NTFS permissions needed to go where:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288991